# How to modify a field in each element of list in java 8 using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
class Employee 
{
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //...
    //Getters and setters for all fields
}

public class Address
{
    private String city;
    private Timestamp startDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;
    private String typeOfResidence;
    private String businessCode;
    private String businessType;


    //...
    //Getters and setters for all the fields
}
```

Now I have an employee object which has list of addresses. Based on businessCode, I need to populate businessType.

The businessCode is already populated.

I have a function

```
public String public getBusinessType(String businessCode){
...

business logic...

return businessType;
}
```

Now please help to update businessType field in each address element.

I am trying using

```
List<Address> l = employee.getAddress();

IntStream.range(0, l.size).forEach();
```

But not sure how to call getBusinessType for each address element and update the field in each address element.

Comment: `employee.getAddress().forEach(a->a.setBusinessType(...))`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in place without the need to stream:

```
yourList.forEach(x -> {
   x.setBusinessType(YourClass.getBusinessType(x.getBusinessCode())) 
})
```

Comment: You don't need to make it a block. A `void` method is a valid lambda expression for `forEach()`.

Comment: @Andreas yup, I know that. I sometimes do that for clarity

Answer (score 2):

The classic way using a *for-each* loop would be :

```
for(Address a :  employee.getAddress()){
    a.setBusinessType(getBusinessType(a.getBusinessCode()));
}
```

Using `Streams` it would be :

```
employee.getAddress().stream().forEach(a-> a.setBusinessType(getBusinessType(a.getBusinessCode())));
```

**But** (a good IDE would tell you that) the `stream()` is superfluous here; `List.forEach()` is sufficient:

```
employee.getAddress().forEach(a-> a.setBusinessType(getBusinessType(a.getBusinessCode())));
```

Answer (score -2):

Should be like this

```
employee.getAddress().stream().map(address->address.setBusinessType(getBusinessType(address.getBusinessCode())))
         .collect(Colletors.toList());
```

also you can use [**replaceAll**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method.

To readability create `UnaryOperator<T>` and then use this function in `replaceAll` method.

```
 UnaryOperator<Address> updateBusinessType = address -> {
        address.setBusinessType(...);
        return address;
    };

employee.getAddress().replaceAll(updateBusinessType);
```

It can also be improved by defining a method in the `Address` class that update `businessType` property.

Comment: `replaceAll()` requires a `UnaryOperator<Address>`, but `setBusinessType` does not return a modified `Address` object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point of replacing all values in the list with the values that are already there. Using `forEach()` is much better. Using `replaceAll()` is just confusing, because we'd then sit there and try to figure out what you're replacing, and that's a waste of time, since you're not actually replacing the `Address` objects in the list. Or is that an exercise in code obfuscation. A bad one if so.

Answer (score -2):

Refer below line.

```
    employee.getAddresses().forEach(employee-> employee.setCity("My City"))
```